# Changed my Azure App Service to PHP 8.1, nginx keeps returning 404

Tags: php, azure, nginx, cakephp, azure-web-app-service

I'm attempting to move a CakePHP app to an Azure App Service with PHP 8.1 from PHP 7.4. I'm having difficulty figuring out the required nginx configurations to make it work.

I took the base nginx configuration, added the changes from the CakePHP book and I'm injecting the configuration file during startup (`cp /home/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`).

I keep getting 404 errors except on the root page. On the index page, layout issues are also occurring due to those links returning 404 too.

```
server {
    #proxy_cache cache;
        #proxy_cache_valid 200 1s;
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;
    #root /home/site/wwwroot;
    root /home/site/wwwroot/webroot;
    #index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    index  index.php;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com; 
    port_in_redirect off;

    #location / {            
    #    index  index.php index.html index.htm hostingstart.html;
    #}

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /html/;
    }
    
    # Disable .git directory
    location ~ /\.git {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    #added from CakePHP book
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    #added from CakePHP book
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    # Add locations of phpmyadmin here.
    #location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    #    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
    #    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    include fastcgi_params;
    #    fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
    #    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    #    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
    #    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    #    fastcgi_connect_timeout         300; 
    #    fastcgi_send_timeout           3600; 
    #    fastcgi_read_timeout           3600;
    #    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    #    fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
    #    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    #    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    #}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed to add the `service nginx restart` command following the copy. Seems to work now.